# Safari overflow scroll with box shadow - still able to get a handle on overflown element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrollable `ul` with a box shadow, in Safari (11.1.2) when I hover over the area where the box shadow appears, the `onmouseover` event fires for the `li` that is actually out of sight, i.e. overflown

[Link: Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4aLbxj3g/42/)

```css
#option-list {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
}
```

```html
<ul id="option-list">
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">1</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">2</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">3</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">4</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">5</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">6</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">7</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">8</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">9</li>
  <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">10</li>
</ul>
```

Any thoughts on how to get around this? i.e. I don't want to be able to get handle on `li` items that are out of view.

See screenshot - I haven't scrolled at this point, simply hovered over the drop shadow and I am getting a handle on the 4th option as shown in the console log.

[image]

Comment: Works for me. What browser version are you on ? I'm on 11.1.1 (13605.2.8)

Comment: Version 11.0.3 (13604.5.6) - i'll try an upgrade

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Safari 11

Comment: Upgraded to 11.1.2 and still occurs

Comment: attached a screenshot of the console log

Comment: I am Safari 11.0.2 and cannot reproduce. As a work around, you could just wrap the `ul` in a div and put the shadow on the div

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Huangism suggested, you can make the shadow on the div outsite as to prevent the event from triggering.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#option-list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 25px -5px rgba(61, 61, 61, 0.41);
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.shadow:before {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.shadow:after {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <ul id="option-list">
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">1</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">2</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">3</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">4</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">5</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">6</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">7</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">8</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">9</li>
    <li onmouseover="console.log(this)">10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```